# omp_set_nested routine deprecated, please use omp_set_max_active_levels instead

Tags: visual-studio-code, openmp, deprecated, pytorch-lightning

I started getting the following warning repeatedly when running my PyTorch Lightning deep learning scripts, at execution start and then all through the training:

> *"OMP: Info #276: omp_set_nested routine deprecated, please use omp_set_max_active_levels instead."*

I get them when executing the main.py script; my scripts are publicly available [here](https://github.com/Antoine101/UrbanSound8K/tree/main/deep%20learning%20scripts).

Symptoms:

- I don't think it has anything to do with PyTorch Lightning, maybe even PyTorch.
- It appeared overnight, so I don't know what could cause it.
- It runs fine without those warnings on my PC.
- I get the warnings when I run from my M1 Mac.
- I use VSCode for both, each up to date.
- I use separate miniconda environments.

Comment: Had the same problem with the python `umap` package. For me, `pip install numba==0.56.0` worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to reply!

I managed to sort myself out in the end.
I spotted the numba package in my miniconda env, which is a Python compiler and that seemed to be the root of the problem.
It was version 0.55.2 but the last version to date is 0.56.0. Trying to upgrade it via conda or pip didn't work for some reason (the 0.55.2 version couldn't be replaced).
I recreated my env step by step, and noticed this package comes with torch-audiomentations, a package for audio data augmentation for deep learning, under torch, that I use.
Re-installing it had numba version 0.56.0 installed properly, and the warnings disappeared.

Comment: To force the update of numba you can force the numba chanel (instead of conda-forge) with `conda install -c numba numba==0.56.2`.

Comment: @Louis-Amand Switching to numba 0.56.2 does not remove the warning for me :/ (M1 MacBook Pro, macOS Monterey)

Comment: It has actually come back for me..

Answer (score 0):

That routine is deprecated, meaning that newer standards want you to use another routine. If you can not edit the code, just ignore. For now it's only an info message. You got that message when you switched to a newer OS / compiler version / OpenMP version.